# .day() returns wrong day of month with Moment.js

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I am using Moment.js to parse a string and get the day, month and year separately:

```
var date = moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY");
var day = date.day();
```

However, `day` is not 25—it's 1. What is the correct API method?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

The correct function to use is [`.date()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/date/):

```
date.date() === 25;
```

[`.day()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/) gives you the day of the week. This works similarly to javascript's [`.getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) and [`.getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) functions on the [date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

If you want to get the month and year, you can use the [`.month()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/) and [`.year()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/year/) functions.

Comment: date.month() returns 11 instead of 12. It always returns -1 the entered month.

Comment: @YaronLevi yeah, it's zero indexed. It talks about that in [the documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/). The javascript date object does that too.

Comment: Wow that's confusing. They should just make 'day' represent day and then have a separate one for 'dayOfMonth'.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `moment().format('DD')` to get the day of month.

```
var date = +moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY").format('DD'); 
// notice the `+` which will convert 
// the returned string to a number.
```

Good Luck...

Answer (score 10):

This how to get parts of date:

```
var date = moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY");

if (date.isValid()) {

    day = date.date(); 
    console.log('day ' + day);

    month = date.month() + 1;
    console.log('month ' + month);

    year = date.year(); 
    console.log('year '+ urlDateMoment.year());

} else {
    console.log('Date is not valid! ');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`.day()`, is getting the day number of the week which output values ( 1 - 7 ) starting from Monday.

If the day is

1. Monday will output 1
2. Tuesday will output 2
3. Wednesday will output 3
4. Thursday will output 4
5. Friday will output 5
6. Saturday will output 6
7. Sunday will output 7

To get the day of the month as @David mentioned, you need to use .date()
Ex:

```
const today = moment().date()
```